# How to make grid scale in 3d view?

Tags: 3d-view

While working in blender I accidentally pressed some buttons from keyboard and mouse which made the grid look strange in 3d view (attached screenshot). How can I get the grid to it's default state, like when you open blender for the first time? 
I tried to make a new file, but when I append the object the grid changes back, like in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the properties panel right from your viewport (press <kbd>N</kbd> if not visible) you can change grid settings as you need them.

[image]

Comment: Changing the scale fixes the problem. It's strange because by default it's 0.1, after I pressed the buttons the grid shrunk, but that scale value was still 0.1, it hadn't change. I'll set it to 1 and move on. Will be more careful not to press random keys in blender, no telling what I might brake :)). Thanks you both for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the scale of your object was (accidentally?) changed, please check that rather than investigating the grid.
The only settings of the grid is available in the N panel:

[image]